# Apache Directory Studio not loading Root DSE

Tags: macos-big-sur, apache-directory

I'm unable to get Apache Directory Studio to load the Root DSE for Oracle Unified Directory.  I recently upgraded my Mac to BigSur and the error started.  I'm also having the same issue on my brand new Windows PC.  I upgraded to the latest version of Apache Directory Studio and have tried various versions of Java.

Version: 2.0.0.v20210213-M16

```
Session Info
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=16.0.1
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  /studio-rcp/resources/icons/linux/studio.xpm -keyring /Users/kathryn.e.sanders@sherwin.com/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 /studio-rcp/resources/icons/linux/studio.xpm -keyring /Users/kathryn.e.sanders@sherwin.com/.eclipse_keyring
```

Error:

```
*org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.api.ControlFactory.decodeValue(org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.Control, byte[])" because "factory" is null (Hexdump: 30 32 02 01 07 65 07 0A 01 00 04 00 04 00 A0 24 30 22 04 17 31 2E 33 2E 36 2E 31 2E 34 2E 31 2E 32 36 30 32 37 2E 31 2E 35 2E 34 01 01 FF 04 04 30 02 04 00)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1128)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.flushMessageReceived(SslHandler.java:330)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:552)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1128)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:643)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:539)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$1200(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1222)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1211)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:683)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.api.ControlFactory.decodeValue(org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.Control, byte[])" because "factory" is null
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.actions.controls.StoreControlValue.action(StoreControlValue.java:81)
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.actions.controls.StoreControlValue.action(StoreControlValue.java:49)
    at org.apache.directory.api.asn1.ber.grammar.AbstractGrammar.executeAction(AbstractGrammar.java:136)
    at org.apache.directory.api.asn1.ber.Asn1Decoder.treatTLVDoneState(Asn1Decoder.java:604)
    at org.apache.directory.api.asn1.ber.Asn1Decoder.decode(Asn1Decoder.java:740)
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.protocol.mina.LdapProtocolDecoder.decode(LdapProtocolDecoder.java:137)
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.protocol.mina.LdapProtocolDecoder.decode(LdapProtocolDecoder.java:86)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:254)
    ... 20 more*
```